# Different resources for different screen sizes (in pixels)

Tags: android, android-layout, porting, dpi, screen-size

Is there a build-in functionality to provide different resources for different screen sizes (**in pixels**)

What I found is a solution to separate them by dpi (using *hdpi*, *ldpi*, *mdpi* or *sw320dp*,  *sw720dp* folders):
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

But I don't care about densities!
My application mostly uses Bitmaps and Canvas, and all I want is to avoid scaling (and smoothing) of these bitmaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I don't care about densities! My application mostly uses Bitmaps
>   and Canvas, and all I want is to avoid scaling (and smoothing) of
>   these bitmaps.

Have you tried using `drawable-nodpi` or `raw` for your bitmaps?

Comment: Ok, it looks like the only option - to put resources in drawable-nodpi or raw and separate them manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify by exact pixel sizes but there are 4 categories that you can use as modifiers to your layout folders. layout-small, layout-normal, layout-large, layout-xlarge.